# Infinite sum of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the value of $$\sum_{r=1} ^\infty \frac{r^3+(r^2+1)^2}{(r^4+r^2+1)(r^2+r)}$$
I tried converting the general term into partial fractions but the $$(r^2+1)^2$$ in the numerator is creating problems to do the sum. Please can somebody explain how can I compute the infinite sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the numerator as $(r^4+r^2+1)+(r^3+r^2)$ to get $$\frac 1{r^2+r}+\frac r{r^4+r^2+1}$$

And go from there.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$r^4+r^2+1=(r^2+r+1)(r^2-r+1)$

Write denominator as product of $r(r^2-r+1)$ and $(r+1)(r^2+r+1)$

As $f(x)=x(x^2-x+1),f(x+1)=?$

Comment: Now use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: I love this trick, completing the square and arriving at this great substitution. +1 on my end